# Concrete5.7 package translation doesn't work

Tags: translation, multilingual, concrete5-5.7

I'm trying to translate my package going by the steps in this Howto: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/translate-your-package/.

For example, I have this:

```
echo $form->label('name', t('Your Name'), array ('class'=>"required"));
```

then gone through all the steps creating my messages.po and messages.mo files - it didn't work, the text doesn't get translated. The po and mo files are in my `application/packages/MY_PACKAGE/languages/ru_RU/LS_MESSAGES`  folder.

I tried another HowTo: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/translating-site-specific-texts/. I've renamed my messages files to `ru_RU.po` and `ru_RU.mo` and moved them to `application/languages/site` - still doesn't work, I only see English.

Then I've uninstalled my package, installed it again. I go the an English page - ok. Then go to a Russian page and get this error:

```
Zend \ I18n \ Exception \ RuntimeException
Plural rule of merging text domain is not compatible with the current one
```

What's wrong? I'm totally clueless now what to do. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Is Russian language installled on site level?

Comment: The correct path for packages is:`/packages/package_handle/languages/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`. Exactly this way, incluuding capital letters

Comment: Yes, of course Russian language is installed. And my path for package is exactly like that (I just called my package handle MY_PACKAGE)

Comment: Sry to ask again but its MY_PACKAGE or my_package? And its LC_MESSAGES or LS_MESSAGES?

Comment: Yes, it's my_package and LC_MESSAGES

Comment: So the 1. HowTo is correct. I did that one too and it worked. Do you use poedit for linux? Did the poedit saved the .mo files in the right directory?

Comment: I followed the 1st HowTo exactly. I wrote shell scripts to make all those files with the given commands. So, everything was in the right folders. I even edited the .po files by hand just to make sure. But I'm not sure if the .po and .pot file headers are correct - does any of that stuff have any effect? Because the commands I used generated headers different to those, for example, in a login block package (an example multulingual package I used for reference too).

Comment: Here are my commands `xgettext --language=PHP --force-po -o %o %C %K %F` but I think I can't help you really. Did you try a fresh install of c5 (without content)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and seem like managed to solve it. I've answered to you on Concrete5 community forum. Here is the [link](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/internationalization/error/).

Seems like it is some kind of a Concrete5 bug, Zend Internationalization Module throws this exception. Solution is to comment 3 lines of code, look at the screenshot I've [provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNBTG.png) for details